# Using arrays in listview adapter declaring the number of elements

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a custom listview adapter. I can populate it from string arrays, but I should know how many strings there are.

This is Activity with listview:

```
public class MainListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private TextView myText;
    private ArrayList<ListData> catalog;
    String[] names = { some names };
    String[] desc = {some description };
    int[] cost = { prices };
    int[] img = { images };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleMain);

        catalog = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            catalog.add(new ListData(names[i - 1], cost[i - 1], img[i - 1],
                    desc[i - 1]));
        }

        CatalogAdapter catAdapter;
        catAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(this, catalog);
        setListAdapter(catAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here I must specify the number of elements:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    catalog.add(new ListData(names[i - 1], cost[i - 1], img[i - 1],
    desc[i - 1]));
```

This is ListData activity:

```
public class ListData {
    String title;
    int price;
    int image;
    String discribe;

    ListData(String _title, int _price, int _image, String _discribe) {
        title = _title;
        price = _price;
        image = _image;
        discribe = _discribe;
    }
}
```

Also I have AdapterActivity, but I think that I should change something in this two activities. So how should I change the code below to not to declare the number of elements in array?
Please, help.

Comment: what do you mean? Does the size of names and desc change during runtime? If not simply code your loop like so: for (int i = 1; i <= names.length; i++) {..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays like `String[]` are not designed to do such things. Use `List` or `ArrayList` instead. You don't have to declare their size.

(If I understood you well and the size of `names` shouldn't be constant.)